# Inserting string into another string using replace and substring functions

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function which will replace text from one string with another string, However it is not inserting the string where I would expect it to.

here for example I would like to change 'text' in my ssml string to 'different text'.

```js
let ssml = `<speak><audio src="someurl.mp3"></audio> text </speak>`;

let temp = [];
for (let x = 0; x < ssml.length; x++) {
  if (ssml[x] === '>') {
    temp.push(x);
  }
}
let firstTag = temp[temp.length - 2];

temp = [];

let secondTag = (ssml.lastIndexOf('<'));
console.log(firstTag);
console.log(secondTag);
ssml = ssml.replace(ssml.substring(firstTag, secondTag), '>' + "different text");


console.log(ssml);
```

My first tag and second tag are coming out at position 78 and 79, I then try this substring method. However this code seems to be placing my replacement string in an entirely different position(index 7 and 8).

Any help would be great cheers!

Comment: Why are you looping through the entire string in lines 4-8? Are you trying to detect HTML tags somehow? And if so, why? Why not just use a regular expression or a straight `ssml.replace("text", "different text")`?

Comment: executing your code, it looks like it is placed in the right position

Comment: I made this a snippet — it seems to be replacing `text` with `different text`. Maybe you can clarify what you want as a final result.

Comment: To me it seems like it would be much easier to stick the string into a detached span, then set the contents of the span with the nested audio, plus whatever replacement text you want.

Comment: Seems like a string literal template would make sense here....